# DiffTech: Compare similar technologies based on StackOverflow data

Tags: app, website

## Screenshots

### Homepage

[image]

### Compare page

[image]

## About

This website compares a large set of similar technologies. We use the data dump from Stack Overflow, extract sentences that compare two technologies, and summarize them to produce an overall opinion given certain similar technologies.

Given two similar techs, we render:

- Definition from tag wikis;
- Users opinions on two technologies;
- Technology trends in Stack Overflow;
- Comparative sentences that are clustered based on their aspects;

## Website

You can access the page at [https://difftech.herokuapp.com](https://difftech.herokuapp.com/)

## License

No licenses, it's free to use.

## Contact

It's a platform that is still underdeveloped. Please feel free to contact me for any questions, bugs, suggestions. My email is freddie.wanah@gmail.com .